# Python3.3 cx_freeze exe compile

Tags: python, compilation, exe, python-3.3, cx-freeze

Once compiled the terminal immediately exits, despite an input() function that waits for user input in the program. running the executable from cmd prompt gave me the following:

```
C:\Python33\build\exe.win-amd64-3.3>chat.exe Traceback (most recent
call last):   File
"C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py",
line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)   File "chat.py", line 28, in <module>   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in
_find_and_load   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1525, in
_find_and_load_unlocked   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in
set_package_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in
set_load er_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in
_require s_frozen_wrapper   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in
load_mod ule   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\threading.py", line 11, in <module>   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in
_find_and_load   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1525, in
_find_and_load_unlocked   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in
set_package_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in
set_loader_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in
_requires_frozen_wrapper   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in
load_module   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\traceback.py", line 3, in <module>   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in
_find_and_load   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1525, in
_find_and_load_unlocked   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in
set_package_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in
set_loader_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in
_requires_frozen_wrapper   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in
load_module   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\linecache.py", line 10, in <module>   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in
_find_and_load   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1525, in
_find_and_load_unlocked   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 497, in
set_package_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 510, in
set_loader_wrapper   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 608, in
_requires_frozen_wrapper   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 713, in
load_module   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\tokenize.py", line 28, in <module>   File
"C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1558, in
_find_and_load   File "C:\Python\64-bit\3.3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1522, in
_find_and_load_unlocked ImportError: No module named 're'
```

The setup.py file looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

EXE = 'chat'
filename = EXE+'.py'

setup(
    name = EXE ,
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "" ,
    executables = [Executable(filename)] ,
    )
```

the command I ran to compile was:

```
python.exe setup.py build
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the module `re` in your python script. I'm not sure why, but when I use cxfreeze I also have to import that module in order for it to work. So just add the line 

`import re`
on the top of your code before running cxfreeze and it should do the job.

Comment: This is a bug in cx_Freeze - it will be fixed in the next version, which is hopefully coming out in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = ["sip","re","atexit"]
exe = Executable(script="chat.py",base="Win32GUI",icon = "images/icon.ico")
setup(options = {"chat": {"includes":includes}},executables = [exe])
```

the inclusion of this list: **includes** into the **setup** is important

Comment: Great!, I did the includes exactly in the order that you've given and it worked!